# boost::erase_all to erase multiple chars from a string

Tags: c++, string, boost

If I want to remove all ones from a string using `boost::erase_all`, I can do this:

```
boost::erase_all( "a1b1c1", "1" );
```

Now, my string is "abc". However, if I want to remove all digits (0 - 9) from a string, using `boost::erase_all`, I have to call it once for each digit I wish to remove.

```
boost::erase_all( "a1b2c3", "1" );
boost::erase_all( "a1b2c3", "2" );
boost::erase_all( "a1b2c3", "3" );
```

I thought I could use `boost::is_any_of` to remove them all at once as that works with other boost string algorithms such as `boost::split`, but is_any_of does not seem to work with erase_all:

```
boost::erase_all( "a1b2c3", boost::is_any_of( "123" ) );

// compile error
boost/algorithm/string/erase.hpp:593:13: error: no matching 
function for call to ‘first_finder(const   
boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>&)’
```

Perhaps I've over-looked something obvious here or there's another function within boost that's meant to do this. I can do it manually with standard C++, but just curious how others might be using boost to do this.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do you have a more complex task that you are trying to accomplish than this?  Because for your particular task, the standard library method would be a very easy one liner.  The advantage of `boost::erase_all` is that it is able to identify and erase *sequences* of characters.  You, however, are only trying to erase single characters, for which `std::remove_if` is perfectly suited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

boost has a version of remove_if that doesn't require you to pass in begin and end iterators, but you will still need to call erase on the string with the end iterator.

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm/remove_if.hpp>
...
std::string str = "a1b2c3";
str.erase(boost::remove_if(str, ::isdigit), str.end());
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/remove_if.html

Comment: hm, but what will you do if it is not about digits but let's say special characters (for example `"-><&%`) ?

Comment: @CarstenGreiner: You could use `boost::is_any_of("-><&%")` in place of `::isdigit`

Answer (score 10):

Also available now is:

`boost::remove_erase_if(str, boost::is_any_of("123"));`